# Differentiability of $f(z)=|z|$ at origin

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

I have referred previous same type of question.I know that using Cauchy-Riemann equations and definition we can prove that this function is nowhere differentiable.

But here I have one more way to check differentiabilty at $(0,0)$. As we know that if function is differentiable at z then all first order partial derivatives must be continuous at that point.

Now consider $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{mx}{x\sqrt{1+m^2}}=\frac{m}{\sqrt {1+m^2}}$$  along $y=mx$

Since this limit depends on the path .Hence not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Therefore $f(z)=|z|$ is not differentiable at $0$.
I just want to no for any correction and whether my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you set $y=mx$ in $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, you don't get $\frac{mx}{x\sqrt{1+m^2}}$. Where the $m$ in the numerator comes from?

Also you should add an absolute value: $\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2} = |x|\sqrt{1+m^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach is not correct because if the function has continuous partial derivatives at a point then it is differentiable at that point. But the converse is not necessarily true. You cannot prove a function is not differentiable by showing that the partial derivatives are discontinuous.